# how to set up a dynamic terraform plan in bash?

Tags: bash, terraform

i want my terraform command plan to have some additional variable override according to if some variables are setted up prior in the bash script.

that is to say: the usual `terraform plan` i want to expand to `terraform plan -var="foo=bar"` if some variable is set up.

i tried up

`terraform plan "${_TERRAFORM_DOCKER_IMAGE_OPTION:-}"`

but this fails due to the terraform error:

> Too many command line arguments. Configuration path expected.

is there a way to do a *dynamic* plan command for terraform?

---

the bash script is a slight modification of the bash SIMPLE boilerplate by alphabetum.
https://github.com/alphabetum/bash-boilerplate/blob/master/bash-simple

with a couple of conditionals to create the `-var` strings.

```
if [[ -n "${_DOCKER_IMAGE}" ]]
  then
    _TERRAFORM_DOCKER_IMAGE_OPTION="-var=\"app_image=${_DOCKER_IMAGE}\""
fi
```

after the variable strings are setted up, i try to use them in the terraform plan command as:

`terraform plan "${_TERRAFORM_DOCKER_IMAGE_OPTION}" "${_TERRAFORM_APPLICATION_COUNT_OPTION}"`

what i expect is the terraform plan to work without parameters when the vars are unset, or use the respective -var strings when they are setted up

Comment: what value do you have for `_TERRAFORM_DOCKER_IMAGE_OPTION`? Note that `${_TERRAFORM_DOCKER_IMAGE_OPTION:-}` will produce a null if the variable is not set. Usually, that syntax is used like `${_TERRAFORM_DOCKER_IMAGE_OPTION:-myDefaultValue}` . Sorry, no experience with terraform. Good luck!

Comment: What do your bash script look like ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

Sample output when run... as you can see i just echo out the terraform plan command plus the variables..

```
export TF_VAR_region=eu-west-1
export TF_VAR_ami=ami-12434555666633
export TF_VAR_name=development

bash-3.2$ ./terraform.sh 
terraform plan  -var="region=eu-west-1" -var="ami=ami-12434555666633" -var="name=development"
```

```
#! /bin/bash

VarsArray=()

if [[ -z "$TF_VAR_region"  ]]
then
      echo "\$TF_VAR_region is empty"
else
      ### add to terraform command array
      VarsArray+=('-var="region='$TF_VAR_region'"')

fi

if [[ -z "$TF_VAR_ami" ]]
then
      echo "\$TF_VAR_ami is empty"
else
  ### add to terraform command array
  VarsArray+=('-var="ami='$TF_VAR_ami'"')

fi

if [[  -z "$TF_VAR_name"  ]]
then
      echo "\$TF_VAR_name is empty"
else
  ### add to terraform command array
  VarsArray+=('-var="name='$TF_VAR_name'"')

fi
tfCommand=$(printf " %s " "${VarsArray[@]}")
tfCommand=${tfCommand:1}
echo "terraform plan " $tfCommand
```

If you commit a certain variable... or leave them out all together, you get your normal... `terraform plan` command

```
bash-3.2$ unset TF_VAR_ami
bash-3.2$ ./terraform.sh 
$TF_VAR_ami is empty
terraform plan  -var="region=eu-west-1" -var="name=development"



unset TF_VAR_region
unset TF_VAR_ami
unset TF_VAR_name
./terraform.sh                     
$TF_VAR_region is empty
$TF_VAR_ami is empty
$TF_VAR_name is empty
terraform plan
```

Comment: did your "terraform plan" work when the array is empty? (without echoing)

Comment: I think I understand you...

in my script i'm just echoing out the terraform plan command you would possibly run . 

so if no variables were set the array will be empty and your command will just be `terraform plan` and if you run it it will run as normal as there are no variables set.